# NextScripts SNAP : not using the permalink in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, custom-fields

This is in a way a followup of this question : [Jetpack Publicize: Sharing only on Twitter for a category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435992/jetpack-publicize-sharing-only-on-twitter-for-a-category/48516745#48516745)

I am currently working on a website in which one of the category only serves as a way to curate news on the net and then, share it on the front page and on Twitter.

The post itself is empty, I use a custom field to receive the URL from the user, grab a few things from the target website, update the permalink and save. Upon saving, SNAP publishes the post on Twitter.

My issue is that it is not using the permalink but the url of the post itself (which is absolutely empty). Having a look into the plugin's code, I saw that it was using post metas (most notably urlToUse, snap_MYURL) but couldn't determine if it was a priority issue or something else.

I also try to adjust my code to set these meta values to the url I want, to no avail.

Is there a way I could set my custom functions or the SNAP plugin so that the permalink is used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer after a week, neither here nor from SNAP's support. No problem.

The ugly patch I used :

- Jetpack Publicize for all the Twitter updates
- SNAP for the Facebook ones thanks to their ability of posting based on a specific category

It's bloated and I'd love to understand but, sometime, you have to ship